# What's an easy way to give a string a value based on the characters it contains in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, if-statement, character

I'm trying to get a sum value based on what characters a string contains. The character values are determined by me and are somewhat arbitrary ('A' = 1, 'B' = 4, 'C' = 2, etc.). For example, if `string s = "ABC"` then `int value = 7` because 1 + 4 + 2 = 7. What would be an efficient way to write this in C#?

Right now my code looks like this:

```
//Declare variables
string name = JOHN
int i = 0;
int nameValue = 0;
string temp = "";
string[] nameArray;

//Convert name to string array so I can use String.Contains() to check what letters are in name
foreach (char c in name)
{
   temp += c.ToString();
   temp += ".";
}

temp = temp.Remove(temp.Length - 1, 1);
nameArray = temp.Split('.');            

//Determine nameValue by iterating through nameArray and checking each string
foreach (string s in nameArray)
{
   if (nameArray[i].Contains('A')) { nameValue += 1 }
   else if (nameArray[i].Contains('B')) { nameValue += 4 }
   else if (nameArray[i].Contains('C')) { nameValue += 2 }
   else if (nameArray[i].Contains('D')) { nameValue += 3 }
   .
   .
   .
   else if (nameArray[i].Contains('Y')) { nameValue += 7 }
   else if (nameArray[i].Contains('Z')) { nameValue += 5 }

   i++;
}

Console.WriteLine(nameValue);
```

I changed the string to a string array because I have names that have repeating letters (i.e. Jill), and I want to give *every* letter in the name a value. If I used String.Contains() without separating every letter, it would only count repeating letters once, I think.

I feel like there has to be a better way than doing all that string manipulation and using a separate conditional statement for every letter in the alphabet, but I couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: What immediately comes to mind is to store your mappings in a `Dictionary<char,int>` and use that for a simple lookup/sum operation.

Comment: If the values are arbitrary anyway, why did you pick such hard-to-work-with values? You could, for example, just use the Unicode values for each character, or if you are using only ASCII characters, their ASCII values. If you are using only alphabetic characters and what the values in a range of 1 to 26, you can use the character value and subtract 64. Beyond on all that though, "is there a better way" is primarily opinion based. If your code works, then it's fine and there's no practical programming problem that would make it on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map *consequent* characters (say, `'A'..'Z'`) to integer values, I suggest using *array*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  int[] map = new int[] {
    //TODO: put corresponding integer values starting from 'A'
    4, 2, 3
  };  

  ...

  s = "ABC";

  int sum = s.Sum(c => map[c - 'A']);
```

In *general* case, if you want to map *arbitrary* symbols, you can use *dictionary*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  Dictionary<char, int> map = new Dictionary<char, int>() {
    //TODO: put all required pairs here
    {'A', 4},
    {'B', 2},
    {'C', 1},
    {'#', -123},
  };

  ...

  s = "ABC";

  // if there's no map (e.g. for '*'), we assume the value being 0
  int sum = s.Sum(c => map.TryGetValue(c, out int v) ? v : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asciitable.com/

you will see that capitol A is 65

```
string str = "Hi there";
foreach(char c in str.ToUpper())
{
    value += ((int)c) - 64;
}
```

Comment: I should comment mine assumed you only care about letters.  If you want to map other symbols, a dictionary would make more sense.   If you are just using letters and numbers my method would be ok